# C# - Error CS1928: Checking for list element with derived class

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have custom class deriving from a library (Satsuma) like so:

```
public class DCBaseNode : Node {
    public bool selected = false;
}
```

and a `Neighbors` method in the library that returns `List<Node>`.  I want to be able to do this:

```
graph.Neighbors(theNode).Any(n => n.selected == true);
```

But `Any` sees `n` as a `Node`, not `DCBaseNode`, so it doesn't understand `.selected`.

So I tried:

```
graph.Neighbors(theNode).Any<DCBaseNode>(n => n.selected == true);
```

...which gives me this error:

> Error CS1928: Type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Satsuma.Node>' does not contain a member`Any' and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

...but I'm not clear on how the arguments are invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to downcast...

```
graph.Neighbors(theNode)
    .OfType<DCBaseNode>()
    .Any(n => n.selected);
```

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thank you—I was not aware of the OfType() method.